# Sample Oracle SQL Randomly - in absense of ROWID

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a weird problem in using SAMPLE clause. Why does the First SQL does not work, while the second one works fine.

```
SELECT * FROM SYS.ALL_TABLES SAMPLE(10)   

SELECT * FROM MIDAS.GERMPLASM SAMPLE(10)
```

I'm trying to `SAMPLE` a SQL query not just a table, but I could not figure out how I should use the SAMPLE clause. Is there any other way besides sample clause? Note: I want to do this in a random manner; not the first N rows.

**Update:**

First of all, thank you for reading this Q to help. But I already know that this SQL does not work because the SAMPLE clause is using a hidden column, ROWID. What I don't know is how to do this if ROWID does not exist in the table.

Here is a reproducible example SQL that I try to SAMPLE randomly:

```
SELECT cols.table_name, cols.column_name, cols.position, cons.status, cons.owner, cons.constraint_type
FROM all_constraints cons, all_cons_columns cols
WHERE cons.constraint_name = cols.constraint_name
AND cons.owner = cols.owner
ORDER BY cols.table_name, cols.position
```

I want to get small random subset of data (from query), to compute statistical properties of table columns before fetching everything from DB.

Thank you

Comment: change `sys.all_all_tables` to `sys.all_tables`

Comment: It does not work! I think of two potential problem: 1. There is no primary key to this table; 2. SAMPLE clause using hidden columns like ROWID to sample!

Comment: Instead of sampling views, try sampling the tables upon which the views are based. Best of luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message you get when you try to run the first query is a pretty big clue:

```
ORA-01446: cannot select ROWID from, or sample, a view with DISTINCT, GROUP BY, etc.
```

It's pretty clear to me from this that the `SAMPLE` functionality requires access to [`ROWID`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns008.htm) to work. As `ROWID` is a pseudocolumn that the database uses to physically locate a row, any query where the `ROWID` is indeterminate (such as when the data is aggregated), cannot use `SAMPLE` on the outer query. In the case of `ALL_ALL_TABLES`, the fact that it is a view that combines two tables via `UNION` blocks access to the `ROWID`.

---

From your revised question, the first thing that jumps out at me is that the `SAMPLE` clause must be in the `FROM` clause, between the table name and any alias. I was able to sample in a query with joins like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM   table_a SAMPLE (10) a
       JOIN table_b SAMPLE (10) b 
       ON a.column1 = b.column1
```

Regarding your actual query, I tried using the tables (again, actually views) that you're trying to sample one at a time:

```
select * from all_constraints sample(10)

ORA-01445: cannot select ROWID from, or sample, a join view without a key-preserved table

select * from all_cons_columns sample(10)

ORA-01445: cannot select ROWID from, or sample, a join view without a key-preserved table
```

This message is pretty clear: none of the tables in these views are key-preserved (i.e. guaranteed to return each row no more than once), so you can't sample them.

---

The following query should work to manually create a random sample, using `DBMS_RANDOM`.

```
SELECT   *
FROM     (SELECT cols.table_name,
                 cols.column_name,
                 cols.position,
                 cons.status,
                 cons.owner,
                 cons.constraint_type,
                 DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE rnd
          FROM   all_constraints cons
                 JOIN all_cons_columns cols
                    ON     cons.constraint_name = cols.constraint_name
                       AND cons.owner = cols.owner)
WHERE    rnd < .1
ORDER BY table_name, position
```